# Matlabs print function produces diffrent images (32 vs 64bit)

Tags: matlab, plot, 32bit-64bit

We currently work with Matlab 2007b or newer and try to generate some illustrations. Whenever we store the images on a 64bit machine, the titles are not rendered properly.

You can examine the result with a few lines
    figure
    title('test')
    print('-dmeta', '-painters', 'test.emf')

Do you know what causes the difference?[image: Visual Comparison]

Binary/visual comparison:
[image]

Drop a line if you wish more details.

Comment: What OS is this Matlab running on? What happens if you use 32-bit Matlab on the 64-bit machine, if your OS supports that?

Comment: We use Win7. The installer forbids us to "cross" install the versions.